# How cold can a pile of dry ice nuggets get inside of a vented insulated box?

Tags: phase-diagram

The question:
Dry ice sublimates at -78.5°C at sea level pressure.  So how can I be measuring temperatures as low as -90°C within the box?

The setup:
The box is at sea level and is sealed to be gas-tight.  The box is very well insulated and is filled with approx 15kg of dry ice nuggets (15mm dia x 25 to 50mm long).  Type-T thermocouples inside are recording the temperatures within the box at multiple locations within the zone surrounded by dry ice.  The TCs were calibrated at -75°C and temperature measurements are accurate to ±0.5°C or better.  The dry ice was made by a local dry ice supplier using the common dry ice manufacturing equipment.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the issue (maybe I'm just not considering something).  Why couldn't it be colder than it's sublimation temperature?  At temperatures below that it should still be solid, and would still turn gaseous near instantly due to the high temperatures you would expose it to.

Answer (score 2):

CO2 phase diagram suggests that reaching -90°C requires unrealistically low pressure. So there are 2 options:

1. There is still error in measurement - I would suggest to measure using different type of thermocouple and using different calibration source.
2. Solid CO2 was super-cooled when you've received it. I.e. factory could have cooled it below -78.5°C. You can wait until visible part of it sublimates and then measure again.

Comment: I would bet on 2. After all that is what we do with freezers, we do not keep the ice at 0. It is also reasonable to come out of the factory supercooled so as to compensate for possible losses.